# JAXB unmarshall cast error : DomLoader$State

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I'm using JAXB from the Oracle JDK 1.7 (xjc 2.2.4-2) and got sometimes this error when running on the Unix version of the JDK (not certain it does not happen on Windows as well). Any idea what it could be ?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [... my - class ... ] cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.DomLoader$State
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.DomLoader.startElement(DomLoader.java:104)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ProxyLoader.startElement(ProxyLoader.java:45)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:486)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:465)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:60)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:229)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:112)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:309)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:288)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:238)
```

Comment: Hi @Marc, Did you find solution for this? I have same error on my application.